# Flutterで画面にFitするウィジェットの作成するには

Tags: android, flutter, dart

テキストエディタのような、他のウィジェットを除いた最大限のスペースにTextFieldを広げたいと考えています。

そこで以下のようなコードを書いているのですが、maxlinesを調整することでTextFieldの高さは変わるのですが、デバイスごとに高さが変わり、また、キーボードを表示した際にも表示エリアの高さが変わるため、デバイスや、表示状態に合わせてTextFieldをフィットさせたいと考えています。

表示状態に合わせてフィットさせるには、どのようなコードを書けばよろしいでしょうか。

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("TEST"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'TEXT',
            ),
            Scrollbar(
              child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                reverse: true,
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLines: 10,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Add your text here',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity, // match_parent
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                "BUTTON",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

このようなイメージでしょうか。ご希望の動作となれば幸いです。

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("TEST"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'TEXT',
            ),
            // Containerを最大化
            Expanded( 
              // Containerの中にScrollbar以下を配置
              child: Container( 
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Scrollbar(
                  child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    reverse: true,
                    child: TextField(
                      autofocus: true,
                      // maxLinesを無制限のnullとする
                      maxLines:  null,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Add your text here',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity, // match_parent
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                "BUTTON",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: ポイントとなる部分の (簡単な) 解説も含めてあると、より良い回答になるかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick さん、アドバイスありがとうございます。コード内にコメントを追加しました。